# Prevent button serverclick firing on every page refresh

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, refresh, buttonclick

Anyone know of a way to prevent a button `serverClick` event from firing on page refresh?

Markup:

```
<INPUT id="btnGo" type="button" value="Go" runat="server">
```

VB.net:

```
Public Sub btnGo_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, _
 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.ServerClick
```

The `btnGo_ServerClick` function needs to fire on the button click, but not on page refresh.

I've tried using `IsPostback`, but that is always true- even on the button click.

*N.B. I'd rather not go into the reasons behind why I'm using a serverclick, rather than an `asp:button` and a `click` event. Suffice to say it just isn't suitable for I am doing.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement something like this:
http://www.csharpaspnetarticles.com/2008/12/detect-browser-refresh-to-avoid-events.html

I'm not sure what you're doing in the server click event, but it's probably a better idea to add form validation or a redirect after the form has been submitted.